# How change iOS TableView index Color?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

[image: TableView]

How do I customise the Color and Font of the right side list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971196/how-to-change-color-of-letters-of-sectionindextitlesfortableview check this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274562/customising-the-font-background-colour-of-index-section-bar-in-uitableview

Answer (score 9):

Use `UITableView` methods `sectionIndexColor` and `sectionIndexBackgroundColor`

**Example**

```
tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.red
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: How do I change font?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/758798/1825618

Comment: Bro, you saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can access ***sectionIndexColor*** method of **UITableView**

```
yourTableviewName.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.yourDesiredColor   
yourTableviewName.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.red // as Example i have used red color
```