# Xamarin Forms - sectionIndexTitlesForTableView customisation

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms app in which the customer really wanted to use the iOS 'scrolling alphabet index' that's not supported on Android

I have therefore two UIs for the platforms, but I am now trying to change the default colour of the text on iOS

I've looked into how to do this and it appears to require customising TableView on iOS platform

[How change iOS TableView index Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383268/how-change-ios-tableview-index-color)

```
   tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.red
   tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

My question is how do I then consume that in the view? Because the only code required to have it work on ioS can be shown simply by the Xaml

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          x:Name="ItemList"
          IsGroupingEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding allItems}"
          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Item}"
          GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding IndexLetter}"
          ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          BackgroundColor="Black"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
```

This is a list view, not a table view, so where in the Xamarin Forms could would I reference the Custom Table View Renderer required to alter the colour of the text on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it by using Custom Renderer .

```
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using xxx.iOS;


[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView),typeof(MyTableViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyTableViewRenderer:ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.SectionIndexColor = UIColor.Red;
                Control.SectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. The confusion for me was in how the listview and tableview interacted but it just 'works'